# Stream video from raspberry pi via a Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, video, server, streaming-video, motion

I have a ubuntu server running on a network which is visible outside to the internet. My question is, is there a way to stream the video from the raspberry pi to my Ubuntu server and from there to any Web client on the internet? I have seen ways using Mjpeg,Motion,VLC etc. But the point here is we should know the internal IP of the Pi which I want to avoid and make it visible to the internet without port-forwarding on my router. Are there any ways to achieve this feat?

Comment: You need a proxy in your ubuntu server. If you looking for RTSP proxy you could try http://www.live555.com/proxyServer/

Comment: You don't want port forwarding via the router but you could instead use port forwarding via the Ubuntu box...

Comment: @ mpromonet Thanks. Will look into it. @goldilocks I didn't get you. How to do that on the ubuntu server side?

Comment: You want to connect to the pi *as if* it were the Ubuntu server, right?  So you port forward from the server box to the pi, the same as you would with a router.  You would do this via **iptables**. Questions about port forwarding on linux belong on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), however -- and I guarantee there's a lot of them already, so try to do a little research first and if there's something you don't understand, ask a specific question there.  I'll leave this open for now in case this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: Best solution is `crtmpserver` on your server where clients will connect to. (its very slick) You push a stream to crmpt from wherever (no need to open port on pushing device, ie Raspberry, since its outgoing), then clients connect to crmtpserver, hosted on VPS (digital ocean)? This is a FLV stream and required Flash if emvedding in a webpage. There is no HTML5 way yet. But you can connect to crmtpserver with VLC too. There is a nginx plugin called `nginx-rtmp` which is `crtmpserver` packaged up fro nginx. This also works really well.

Comment: You can do it by using Dataplicity. Which will transfer your linux terminal remotely to the internet from where you can access it. Just visit it. https://www.dataplicity.com

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, based on whether your Ubuntu box is the router or not.

If you are forwarding traffic you can look into using `iptables` with SNAT/DNAT.

Or you can use an application layer gateway that understands the streaming protocols to do this, optionally providing the user with multiple protocol options. For those who uses HTTP Live Stream, `nginx` is a good application layer gateway.

Comment: This does not really answer the question